# Load Database Values dynamically in table asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I am building Online shopping Website and I have a Admin Page in which i can add products in Database. Now, My Exact is question that I am Loading Dynamically values in Product.aspx page but the Values are adding Horizontally in form of cells. 
I want to add rows in asp.table, After every 4 cells. 
Please Help me and Sorry about my English.

Here's the Piece of Code.

```
private void Displaying_Products()
        {
            DataSet ds = obj.searching_product();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = ds.Tables["Register_Product"];

            TableRow row = new TableRow();


            foreach (DataRow dr2 in dt.Rows)
            {


                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                name = dr2["Name"].ToString();
                des = dr2["Description"].ToString();
                price = dr2["Price"].ToString();
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Height = 19;
                btn.Width = 100;
                btn.Text = "Add to Cart";


                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Text = "Brand : " + name + " <br /> " + "Description : " + des + " <br /> " + "Price :" + price + " <br /> " + " <br /> ";
                cell.Controls.Add(lbl); 

                cell.Controls.Add(btn);


                cell.Width = 100;
                cell.Height = 200;
                row2.Cells.Add(cell);


            }

            image_table.Rows.Add(row2);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out a [GridView control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Something like this:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="gridView1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description" DataField="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# ((decimal)Eval("Price")).ToString("c") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Add to Cart" ID="AddToCartBtn" OnClick="AddToCartBtn_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And your code-behind will look similar to this:

```
gridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Register_Product"];
gridView1.DataBind();
```

If you want to continue using the hard way (creating the table itself) then you'll need to move your table row creation statements inside the `foreach` loop.

**EDIT:**

If you're looking to put all of the product info (name, description, price) in a single table cell and have 4 products per row, then you'll need to add a counter to your `foreach` loop like so:

```
int i = 1;
TableRow row = new TableRow();
foreach (DataRow dr2 in dt.Rows)
{
    if (i == 1)
        row = new TableRow();
    // .. further processing
    i++;
    if (i > 4)
        i = 1;
}
```